# How to create dependent dropdown list in angularjs dynamically?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, json, associative-array

I am working on a project where i used below link to fill certain dropdowns.
I want dynamic dependent drop down list  so that i can use it as a filter .
I see some links for dependent drop down list in angular but it shows some static json data. I cant able to create same json data dynamically.

```
{
            'India': {
                'Maharashtra': ['Pune', 'Mumbai', 'Nagpur', 'Akola'],
                'Madhya Pradesh': ['Indore', 'Bhopal', 'Jabalpur'],
                'Rajasthan': ['Jaipur', 'Ajmer', 'Jodhpur']
            },
            'USA': {
                'Alabama': ['Montgomery', 'Birmingham'],
                'California': ['Sacramento', 'Fremont'],
                'Illinois': ['Springfield', 'Chicago']
            },
            'Australia': {
                'New South Wales': ['Sydney'],
                'Victoria': ['Melbourne']
            }
        };
```

i want this kind of data.

Below is my link and json data also that i got from that link.

```
 {$scope.names4 = $scope.names4 = response.data.service;});
  $http.get("xyzsomefile.php")
  .then(function(response) 
  {$scope.names5 = $scope.names5 = response.data.service;});
```

xyzsomefile.php:

```
$candidates = mysql_query("
SELECT i.interview_id
     , i.com_name
     , i.loc_name
     , i.interview_candidate
     , r.candidate_email
     , c.com_name
     , l.loc_name
     , d.dep_name 
  FROM job_interview i
  JOIN final_candidate f
    ON f.interview_id = i.interview_id 
  JOIN resume_records r
    ON r.candidate_name = i.interview_candidate 
  JOIN company_tbl c
    ON c.com_id = f.com_name 
  JOIN location_tbl l
    ON l.loc_id = f.loc_name 
  JOIN department_tbl d
    ON d.dep_id = f.dep_name 
 WHERE i.org_id = $_SESSION[org_id] 
 ORDER 
    BY i.interview_id
  ");

    $company = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($candidates,MYSQL_NUM))
        {
            $company['service'][] = array(
                'candidate_id' => $row[0],        
                'candidate_name' => $row[3],
                'candidate_email' => $row[4],
                'candidate_com' => $row[5],
                'candidate_loc' => $row[6],
                'candidate_dep' => $row[7]          
            );

        }
        echo json_encode($company,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

json data from above link:

```
 {
  "service": [
    {
      "candidate_id": "1",
      "candidate_name": "Name1",
      "candidate_email": "amitsutar119@gmail.com",
      "candidate_com": "Company1",
      "candidate_loc": "com1_loc1",
      "candidate_dep": "com1_loc1_dep1"
    },
    {
      "candidate_id": "3",
      "candidate_name": "Name 3_title_1",
      "candidate_email": "name3@gmail.com",
      "candidate_com": "Company1",
      "candidate_loc": "com1_loc1",
      "candidate_dep": "com1_loc1_dep1"
    },
    {
      "candidate_id": "5",
      "candidate_name": "Smith",
      "candidate_email": "smith@gmail.com",
      "candidate_com": "Company2",
      "candidate_loc": "com2_loc2",
      "candidate_dep": "com2_loc2_dep1"
    },
    {
      "candidate_id": "5",
      "candidate_name": "Smith",
      "candidate_email": "smith@gmail.com",
      "candidate_com": "Company2",
      "candidate_loc": "com2_loc2",
      "candidate_dep": "com2_loc2_dep1"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see first json.  In first dropdown if i choose 'india' then in second dropd down 'maha','madhya' and 'raj' will display. If i choose 'maha' in second drop down then in third drop down list only locations from maharashtra has to display..

Now in my case as You can see second json data... If i choose first drop down then 'candidate_name' should be appears. In second drop down list his candidate_com should be display. In third drop down list his candidate_loc should be display.

Comment: Why do you even need the second and third dropdown? As by looking at your JSON data I don't see that a candidate will have multiple Company nor he/she will have multiple locations. I guess you can have a dropdown for the candidate's name and labels for other fields.

Comment: right bro. candidate will only have one com and loc. but as per my format i have to first select name then select company and then its location. you can refer this link i want exactly same like this. http://www.codescratcher.com/angularjs/cascading-dropdownlist-in-angularjs/#comment-1089

Comment: Please stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

This is not the best implementation(Don't have much time right now), but you can do something like in the given example:

P.S: As I see you are writing the server side code also, you can come up with some good structure to hold the data on the server side.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', MyController)

function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.candidateSel = undefined;
  $scope.selecetedCompany = undefined;
  $scope.selecetdLoc = undefined;

  $scope.listData = [{
    "candidate_id": "1",
    "candidate_name": "Name1",
    "candidate_email": "amitsutar119@gmail.com",
    "candidate_com": "Company1",
    "candidate_loc": "com1_loc1",
    "candidate_dep": "com1_loc1_dep1"
  }, {
    "candidate_id": "3",
    "candidate_name": "Name 3_title_1",
    "candidate_email": "name3@gmail.com",
    "candidate_com": "Company1",
    "candidate_loc": "com1_loc1",
    "candidate_dep": "com1_loc1_dep1"
  }, {
    "candidate_id": "5",
    "candidate_name": "Smith",
    "candidate_email": "smith@gmail.com",
    "candidate_com": "Company2",
    "candidate_loc": "com2_loc2",
    "candidate_dep": "com2_loc2_dep1"
  }, {
    "candidate_id": "6",
    "candidate_name": "Smith",
    "candidate_email": "smith@gmail.com",
    "candidate_com": "Company2",
    "candidate_loc": "com2_loc2",
    "candidate_dep": "com2_loc2_dep1"
  }];

  $scope.getInfo = function() {
    if ($scope.candidateSel) {
      $scope.company = [$scope.candidateSel['candidate_com']];
      $scope.location = [$scope.candidateSel['candidate_loc']];
    }
  };

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">

  <div>
    Names:
    <select id="names" ng-model="candidateSel" ng-options="data.candidate_name for data in listData track by data.candidate_id" ng-change="getInfo()">
      <option value=''>Select</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    Company:
    <select id="company" ng-disabled="!candidateSel" ng-model="selecetedCompany" ng-options="cancompany for cancompany in company">
      <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    Location:
    <select id="location" ng-disabled="!selecetedCompany" ng-model="selecetdLoc" ng-options="canloc for canloc in location">
      <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    Selected candidate: {{ candidateSel['candidate_name'] }}
  </div>
  <div>
    Selected candidate's company: {{ selecetedCompany }}
  </div>
  <div>
    Selected candidate's location: {{ selecetdLoc }}
  </div>

</div>
```